# How do I export a pandas pivot table to be re-imported?

Tags: python, pandas, import, export, pivot-table

I have a pandas pivot table that I would like to share with a 3rd party, but I don't want to share my python code.  The pivot table has a couple of other columns that are joined to it. When I write to_csv and then reread back in some of the formatting is dropped.  
How do I share the pandas pivot table in such a way that he can re-import the file into python without losing any of the data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need more to go on, but possibly look at pickling the file

> df.to_pickle('test.csv')

> df = pd.read_pickle('test.csv')